# WebRTC Audio Streaming without attaching to a html element

Tags: webrtc

With reference to this tutorial. [WebRTC - Voice Demo](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/webrtc/webrtc_voice_demo.htm)

The audio stream is attached to an `<audio />` element for both Local and Remote audio.

I am a bit confused now. Aren't we suppose to connect the local audio to a Mic, instead of playing it?

Besides, for remote audio, is it possible for me to play the audio only without attaching it to an `<audio />` element?

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to create an audio element to play local audio as well.

The moment you call navigator.webkitGetUserMedia with constraints { video: false, audio: true }, you get your mic stream as a parameter on the callback. Then in order to play it, you need to attach it to an audio element, just like you would for remote audio, however, the remote audio stream will come from ontrack event instead.

But honestly, there is no reason for you to play your own local stream since the sound of your voice will overlap with the sound from the audio player. I guess they did it on the tutorial for demonstration purposes.

Btw, this tutorial you referred looks quite old, so if things don't work, that might be the reason why.

Comment: Why do I need to play the local audio? Can't I just send it to the remote without the Audio element?

Yes, the tutorial is a bit outdated, but I managed to get everything working. Just wondering why do we need an Audio element for the local stream

Comment: You don't need to. I don't see why they would have added that on the tutorial, especially because the sound of your voice would be overlapping with the sound coming from your local audio element. I will update my answer to indicate that.